# Simple JWT token , Django rest framework (DRF) accessing the access and refresh token

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, access-token, refresh-token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

When using the simple jwt in django rest framework. what is the best way to access the new access token using the refresh token ?

Using the url ==> api/refresh/token
or
sending the access and refresh token in the header and updating it and reassigning it back to the header

I am building a project , where frontend i am using react and backend drf . so i want to know the best approach for it .